# How to remove the underline from the link on the button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good afternoon! I am reviewing a college paper and wanted to remove the underline from the link inside the button, the underline only appears when hovering over the button. I would like to remove the underline to make the button totally clean, can anyone tell me which tags are used to remove?

```css
body {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.botao {
  width: 30px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.esquerda {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.indicador {
  width: 30px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.indicador:visited {
  width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#compra {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 10%;
  margin-top: 3.5%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>Eco Aero - Viagens</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Boostrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../estilo/style.css">
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="../js/resultadomes.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0" href="index.html">Eco Aero - Viagens</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Início</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="sobre.html">Sobre</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="contato.html">Contato</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="passagensareas.html">Passagens Aéreas</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Entrar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="inscrever.html">Inscrever-se</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="../imagem/slide-01.png" class="img-fluid d-block">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="../imagem/slide-02.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="../imagem/slide-03.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="../imagem/slide-04.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center my-5">
        <h1 class="display-3">Passagens Aéreas</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
        <form name="consulta" method="post">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="escolhaDataIda">Escolha Data de Ida:</label>
              <input type="date" id="escolhaDataIda" class="form-control" name="dataida" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="escolhaDataVolta">Escolha Data de Volta:</label>
              <input type="date" id="escolhaDataVolta" class="form-control" name="datavolta">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
              <a href="listaderesultados.html">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block">Pesquisar</button>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Eco Aero - Viagens</h3>
        <p>A melhor agência de viagens sobre medidas para todos os tipos de pessoas e gostos.Viaje com a gente e venha conhecer novos lugares, culturas e compartilhar as melhores imagens e guardar as melhores lembranças.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <div class="list-group text-center">
          <a href="index.hml" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark">Início</a>
          <a href="sobre.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark">Sobre</a>
          <a href="contato.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark">Contato</a>
          <a href="passagensareas.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark">Passagens Aéreas</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Social</h3>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block btn-group-lg" role="group">
          <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Facebook</a>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="#">Twitter</a>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-warning" href="#">Instagram</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 mt-5">
        <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
          <p class="mb-0">O sucesso não é garantido, mas o fracasso é certo se você não estiver emocionalmente envolvido em seu trabalho.</p>
          <footer class="blockquote-footer">Biz Stone <cite title="Título">Fundador do Twitter</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jquery first, then popper.js, then Bootstrap 3S -->
  <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no button visible from the code you have posted.

Answer (score 3):

Simply added this CSS rule to your existing code in last line

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

```css
body{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.div{
    display:inline-block; 
}

.botao{
    width:30px; 
    height:45px;
    border-radius:25px;
}

.esquerda{
    margin-right:5%;
}

.indicador{
    width:30px; 
    height:45px;
    border-radius:25px;
}

.indicador:visited{
    width:300px; 
    height:45px;
    border-radius:25px;
}

#compra{
    background-color:orange;
    width:10%;
    margin-top:3.5%;
    border-radius:25px;
}

.btn, a {
    text-decoration: none;     
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Eco Aero - Viagens</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        
        <!-- Boostrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../estilo/style.css">
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="../js/resultadomes.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0" href="index.html">Eco Aero - Viagens</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Início</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="sobre.html">Sobre</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="contato.html">Contato</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="passagensareas.html">Passagens Aéreas</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Entrar</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="inscrever.html">Inscrever-se</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="../imagem/slide-01.png" class="img-fluid d-block">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="../imagem/slide-02.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="../imagem/slide-03.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="../imagem/slide-04.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center my-5">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Passagens Aéreas</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
                    <form name="consulta" method="post">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label for="escolhaDataIda">Escolha Data de Ida:</label>
                                <input type="date" id="escolhaDataIda" class="form-control" name="dataida" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label for="escolhaDataVolta">Escolha Data de Volta:</label>
                                <input type="date" id="escolhaDataVolta" class="form-control" name="datavolta">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                <a href="listaderesultados.html">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block">Pesquisar</button>
                                </a> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mb-3"><hr></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h3>Eco Aero - Viagens</h3>
                    <p>A melhor agência de viagens sobre medidas para todos os tipos de pessoas e gostos.Viaje com a gente e venha conhecer novos lugares, culturas e compartilhar as melhores imagens e guardar as melhores lembranças.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h3>Menu</h3>
                    <div class="list-group text-center">
                        <a href="index.hml" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark">Início</a>
                        <a href="sobre.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark">Sobre</a>
                        <a href="contato.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark">Contato</a>
                        <a href="passagensareas.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark">Passagens Aéreas</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h3>Social</h3>
                    <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block btn-group-lg" role="group">
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Facebook</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="#">Twitter</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-warning" href="#">Instagram</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-5">
                    <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
                        <p class="mb-0">O sucesso não é garantido, mas o fracasso é certo se você não estiver emocionalmente envolvido em seu trabalho.</p>
                        <footer class="blockquote-footer">Biz Stone <cite title="Título">Fundador do Twitter</cite></footer>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jquery first, then popper.js, then Bootstrap 3S -->
        <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He wants to remove it on hover , so a:hover {} is the selector

Comment: He meant the underline only appears when the link is hovered. "I would like to remove the underline to make the button totally clean" would mean he wants the underline gone in either case which the code does.

Comment: yeah , but if he has :hover defined somewhere else , that would not override it ... as i can see in his code there is no :hover defined ... so i'm guessing it's default browser behavior ... in order to override that you have to define a:hover {}

Comment: totally agree with your observation. However, as you can see that browser behavior is overriden by user stylesheet even if :hover is not defined.

So in the code above, if you hover over any link, there will be no underline.

Comment: you are right :) the default browser behavior is to have underline all the time, so my bad :D but still if he has underline only on hover , then it has to be defined somewhere , i'm guessing he's not sharing the whole CSS :)